# How can I prove this using number theory only

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

So this book I'm reading has this question:

show that if $(a,n)=(b,n)=1$ the the equation $$ax+by\equiv c(mod( n))$$
has exactly $n$ different solutions.

I was only able to prove it using information that I know from group theory, here's what I did:

since $(a,n)=(b,n)=1$ then the cyclic subgroups of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_{n} $ $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ generated by $a$ and $b$ respectively have order $n$ and thus equal to  $\mathbb{Z}_{n} $. Now if we choose $x$ to be any element in $\mathbb{Z}_{n} $ and let $ax=t$ then by the difinition of a group then there must exist a unique $s\in \mathbb{Z}_{n} $ such that $t+s=c$, and $by=s$ and now if we consider the multiplicative group modulo $n$ then there must exist a unique $b$ that satisfies the equation. Now since we can choose $n$ elements to be $x$ we will get $n$ solutions.

**Can you prove this with just basic knowledge of congruence?**

**Would be great if you can also review my proof**

Comment: You are using $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as a filed not just a group.

Comment: I think it suffices that $(a,n)=1$ or $(b,n)=1$, rather than both be equal to $1$.

Comment: @HoseynHeydari yeah I know that but I haven't really gotten into fields yet so I didn't want to do that just to make sure that I don't make any mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you prove this with just basic knowledge of congruence?

Using [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), for two integers $a$ and $b$, we can write:

$$ax + by = \gcd(a, b) = 1$$

Where $x$ and $y$ are some integers.
Now, knowing that $\gcd(a, n) = \gcd(b, n) = 1$, we can safely write:

$$a(1x) + b(1y) \equiv 1 \mod n$$
$$a(2x) + b(2y) \equiv 2 \mod n$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a(nx) + b(ny) \equiv n \equiv 0 \mod n$$

Comment: What exactly did you prove? I think $c$ is fixed. Besides, $(a,n) = (b,n) = 1$ does not imply that $(a,b) = 1$ (for instance, we could have $a = b$).

Comment: @PedroM. Well, I just realized my error. Also, c is not fixed. If it were, he would've said so, but he accepted the answer. I'd delete it, but you know, I can't delete an accepted answer.

Comment: I believe this might be a homework question, and OP isn't really sure about the subject at hand. In fact, if $c$ is not fixed, then the question is meaningless: any pair $x,y$ satisfies $ax + by \equiv c \pmod n$ for some $c$!

Comment: @PedroM. I see.

Answer (score 2):

If $(a,n) = 1$, Euclid's Algorithm yields that there exist $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $ap+nq = 1$, or $ap \equiv 1 \pmod n$.
Therefore, the equation $ax + by \equiv c \pmod n$ becomes $x \equiv pc - pby \pmod n$, which has exactly $n$ solutions (one value of $x$ for each of the $n$ possible values for $y$).